# Discrepancy in finding derivative of implicit equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I was learning implicit differentiation and came across a discrepancy in finding $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ of $y=x+\frac{1}{y}$:
when differentiating without simplifying there is no $x$ in $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, but after simplifying there is.

When I simplified the equation to $y^2=xy+1$ I got the right answer.
Why did this happen?

I could only conclude it has to do something with how implicit functions are defined. I could not find anything on the internet.

Comment: What's the discrepancy you are facing?

Comment: @Anurag A when differentiating without simplifying you see there will be no x in dy/dx but after simplifying there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By differentiating $y=x+\frac{1}{y}$ we find
$$y'=1-\frac{y'}{y^2} \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, $y^2=xy+1$ gives
$$2yy'=y+xy'\tag{2}$$
(1) and (2) are **both** valid equations.

Infact, by using $x=y-\frac{1}{y}$ in (2), we remove $x$ from (2) and we get (1):
$$2yy'=y+xy'=y+\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)y'$$
that is
$$yy'=y-\frac{y'}{y}$$
and after dividing by $y$ (recall that here $y\not=0$),
$$y'=1-\frac{y'}{y^2}.$$
By reversing the process we may obtain (2) from (1).